# Recalculate columns values based on data from another column

Tags: r, lapply

I have a sample of data that consists of time spent for some tasks in each month for several people. There is also a column "department". I need to take the value of column department and devide its value equally for each person

```
Date    department  name1   name2   name3   name4   name5   name6   name7
2022/05 117.89     85.37    30.30   108.86  14.67   23.90   77.62   23.30
2022/06 69.25      44.00    85.00   113.20  16.28   20.40   56.97   77.85
2022/07 73.55      37.36    85.00   113.20  16.28   35.68   74.86   43.34
2022/08 30.89      41.34    36.34   184.90  20.70   58.79   30.34   72.38
```

And I need to get

```
Date              name1              name2              name3   etc.
2022/05.          85.37+(117.89/7)  30.30+(117.89/7)    108.86+(117.89/7)
```

I am trying to use function lapply but seems that i am doing smth wrong )

```
mydata6 <- lapply(mydata4[3:15], function(x)  {x + x[1]/13} )
```

Comment: you can try `as.data.frame(lapply(d[3:9], function(x)  {x + d$department/7}))`

Answer (score 3):

Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, `cbind` the `Date` column (column 1) to the `name...` columns (all except the first 2) plus the `department` column divided by 7.

```
cbind(DF[1], DF[-(1:2)] + DF$department/7)
##      Date     name1    name2    name3    name4    name5    name6    name7
## 1 2022/05 102.21143 47.14143 125.7014 31.51143 40.74143 94.46143 40.14143
## 2 2022/06  53.89286 94.89286 123.0929 26.17286 30.29286 66.86286 87.74286
## 3 2022/07  47.86714 95.50714 123.7071 26.78714 46.18714 85.36714 53.84714
## 4 2022/08  45.75286 40.75286 189.3129 25.11286 63.20286 34.75286 76.79286
```

Either of these variations would also work.

```
replace(DF, -(1:2), DF[-(1:2)] + DF$department/7)[-2]

replace(DF[-2], -1, DF[-(1:2)] + DF$department/7)
```

Double check the first 3 name values in the first row:

```
c(85.37+(117.89/7), 30.30+(117.89/7), 108.86+(117.89/7))
## [1] 102.21143  47.14143 125.70143
```

### Note

```
DF <-
structure(list(Date = c("2022/05", "2022/06", "2022/07", "2022/08"
), department = c(117.89, 69.25, 73.55, 30.89), name1 = c(85.37, 
44, 37.36, 41.34), name2 = c(30.3, 85, 85, 36.34), name3 = c(108.86, 
113.2, 113.2, 184.9), name4 = c(14.67, 16.28, 16.28, 20.7), name5 = c(23.9, 
20.4, 35.68, 58.79), name6 = c(77.62, 56.97, 74.86, 30.34), name7 = c(23.3, 
77.85, 43.34, 72.38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the tidyverse, this is a job for `across()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      starts_with("name"), 
      function(x) x + department/7
    )
  )
     Date department     name1    name2    name3    name4    name5    name6    name7
1 2022/05     117.89 102.21143 47.14143 125.7014 31.51143 40.74143 94.46143 40.14143
2 2022/06      69.25  53.89286 94.89286 123.0929 26.17286 30.29286 66.86286 87.74286
3 2022/07      73.55  47.86714 95.50714 123.7071 26.78714 46.18714 85.36714 53.84714
4 2022/08      30.89  45.75286 40.75286 189.3129 25.11286 63.20286 34.75286 76.79286
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Please accept the answer so that others do not spend time focusing on a question that has already been answered.